# grep search with filename as parameter

Tags: bash, shell, unix, grep, sh

I'm working on a shell script.

`OUT=$1`

here, the OUT variable is my filename.

I'm using `grep` search as follows:

```
    l=`grep "$pattern " -A 15  $OUT | grep -w $i | awk '{print $8}'|tail -1 | tr '\n' ','`
```

The issue is that the filename parameter I must pass is **test.log**.However, I have the folder structure :

```
   test.log
   test.log.001
   test.log.002
```

I would ideally like to pass the filename as **test.log** and would like it to search it in all log files.I know the usual way to do is by using `test.log.*` in command line, but I'm facing difficulty replicating the same in shell script.

My efforts:

```
    var-$'.*'
    l=`grep "$pattern " -A 15  $OUT$var | grep -w $i | awk '{print $8}'|tail -1 | tr '\n' ','`
```

However, I did not get the desired result.

Comment: you can do with `awk` pretty much anything you could do with `grep/tr/cut`. In that your example is largely inefficient. What are you actually trying to do here?  Post sample input and sample output.

Comment: This is an X-Y problem, rather than stating your question (i.e. input and an expected output), all you have mentioned is why your attempts didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully this will get you closer:

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in "${1}*"; do
   grep "$pattern" -A15 "$f"
done | grep -w $i | awk 'END{print $8}'
```